# What does "thread something through a pipe" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am clueless about the meaning of the words "thread it through a pipe" in the following sentence:

> You can bend a free kick round a wall of defenders, but can you thread
>   it through a pipe so that the ball rolls down the side of an ancient temple into the net?

Could anyone please rephrase the sentence above? This is a description of an app which lets you play football.

Comment: What's the name of the app? And what type of crazy golf has defenders, and a "net" (goal)? This sounds  like footballers (soccer players) rather  than golf players.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It is football.

Comment: Did you search for the meanings of  "thread" (verb), "through"(adverb), "pipe" (noun) and "net" (noun) before asking here?

Comment: Lexical meanings do not always convey the complete meaning.

Comment: Is that a "yes"? You said you were "*clueless about the meanings of the words*", which suggests that you didn't. Unless you're unfamiliar with the game of football (soccer in the US).

Comment: Yes, I know the lexical meaning of the said words.

Comment: @seeeker - Tell us what you understand. That means editing into your question dictionary definitions that you found for those words. And then explaining to us why that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I am confused by the word "pipe" here. What does it signify?

Answer (score 3):

**thread it through a pipe**

From the idiom:

**thread (one's) way through (something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thread) idiom

> To move carefully between people or things that are numerous and close
>   together.

**pipe** - metaphorical - as if through a pipe, avoiding obstacles

Your question:

> ... but can you thread it through a pipe so that the ball rolls down
>   the side of an ancient temple into the net?

... but can you aim the ball so it moves to the side of a building and then maneuvers to the net?

Comment: It's golf, so presumably you're not kicking the ball :P

Comment: Sorry, it is football.